# Android: how to insert an intermediate image when changing item in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I want to make an effect when changing an item in GridView. Particularly, I click an item (e.g: a green circle) -> an intermediate item (an green eclipse) -> final item (a black circle)
[image]

Now, I can change from green circle to black. Someone could teach me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: No one help me. My question is not clear?

Comment: That will maybe help you. You are creating a new XML file which is using  **android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.0"
           android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"** (That is just an example,you can use diffrent parameters or different methods)[LinkIsHere](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/gridview-animation-in-android.html) Basic effects are included SDK on android platform.But you want to use more specific animation,you can use external library or you should try to improve these base effects.

Comment: @TeachMeJava: Thank you. I'll find out about your suggestion. If anyone can know the exactly how to do this, please help me post the answer. I am new in Android

Comment: Sorry, I cant see the vote in your comment. And, I dont know why I cant see the vote for the answers or comments in some my topics